# Error : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

ERROR : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

**Data**

```
profile(id: string) { 
  this.UserProefileServices.Userdetails(id).subscribe((data: Response) => { 
  this.userdata = data["data"]; }); 
}
```

Comment: profile(id: string) {
    this.UserProefileServices.Userdetails(id).subscribe((data: Response) => {
      this.userdata = data["data"];
    });
  }

Comment: what happens with... `profile(id: string) { 
    this.UserProefileServices.Userdetails(id).subscribe(
    (data: Response) => { this.userdata = data; }
    ); 
    }`

Comment: You can (and should) use the [edit] link below a question to include more information. That's uch better than putting things in comments.

Comment: @DevpalSinhChauhan `this.userdata` is must be array type if you have using `*ngFor` not object type error is told to data type is `object`

Comment: @AkberIqbal  i can set of this line this.userdata = data; but object error

Comment: @Abhishek i know about error but how is it solve ?

Comment: what does data look like? output it to console and share.

Comment: @DevpalSinhChauhan, do `console.log(data)` instead of `this.userdata - data;` this will help you check the format of the data which is being returned; then you can make sure that the type of your `this.userdata` is the right format.

Comment: @DevpalSinhChauhan can you provide data format?

Comment: my data format Object
data: {id: 52, userName: "Devpalsinh", password: "ddd", emailAddress: "ddd@gmai.com", address: "Kondh", …}
status: true

Comment: thank you guys it has been solved  from     this.userdata[0]= data['data'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that 'this.userdata' you use in your html *ngFor cycle. *ngFor support only Array, so if this.usetdata is object, you should convert it to array, for example : 
`this.userdata = Object.keys(data["data"]).reduce((arr, key) => {arr.push(data["data"][key]); return arr},[])`